# How can i get the file URL from web element if it calls java script function in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am having some test cases to verify download files using selenium.In there i have handle browser popups automatically and gave a default path to file to be downloaded.

**Handle download popup automatically in Chrome**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory","/downloadpath/");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

This works fine in my local machine.but due to some restrictions above code snippet dont work in selenium grid.As a solution i mimic the browser cookie state and grab the file URL and programmatically write the file into local location like in this [example](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java).But having some problem in this approach. Because it requires web element to contains a `href` attribute to locate the download file URL.In mycase it will calls the java script function on button click to generate the file URL.

**HTML code snippet**

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:downloadFile()" value="Download">.//does not contains href
```

**Js code snippet**

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">   
    function downloadFile() {
       var fileType = document.form.fileType.options[document.form.fileType.selectedIndex].value;
          var boType = "TransportManifest"
             if(fileType == null || fileType == "") {
                window.alert('Please select a file type');
            } else {
                 var format = fileType.substring(0, fileType.indexOf("~~"));
                 var link = "/local/dynamic1234." + format + "?key="+154220756+"&producer=ExportMediaProducer"; // i need to access this generated URL
                 link = link + "&fileType=" + fileType + "&type=" + boType;
                document.location=link;                    
                }
                 } 
      </SCRIPT>
```

Please let me know how can i get the file URL to programmatically download the file.Is there any browser listeners to trigger button click and grab the file URL?

Answer (score 1):

when you click on the element it's suppose to create new frame with the href you need try to inspect the elements after the click.

if it's didn't help download [FIDDLER](http://telerik.com/fiddler)